laravel-dompdf: Page count numerical overlap
Using Laravel Framework 10.48.3
I'm using the following in my scripts tag:
<script type="text/php">
    if (isset($pdf)) {
        $text = "page {PAGE_NUM} / {PAGE_COUNT}";
        $size = 10;
        $font = $fontMetrics->getFont("Verdana");
        $width = $fontMetrics->get_text_width($text, $font, $size) / 2;
        $x = ($pdf->get_width() - $width) / 2;
        $y = $pdf->get_height() - 35;
        $pdf->page_text($x, $y, $text, $font, $size);
    }
</script>

Usage in Controller:
    public function getOutput(): string
    {
        $pdf = PDF::loadView($this->getOutputBladeTemplate(), $this->getOutputData());
        return $pdf->output();
    }

Below is a screenshot of Page 1, there are 2 pages in this document and the total count appears to have a 1 and 2 overlap

On the second page however it appears correctly:

In styling I'm currently using:
    <style>
        header {
            position: fixed;
        }
    </style>

If I remove the fixed position then despite having 2 pages only the first page will show:
image
and then the second will show no page numbering.


Fixed: <main> tag needed to be above <header> tag where this was implemented


Move the script tag to the very end of the document and place it outside of a fixed element. They changed the way the script tag is rendered, see https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/3279#issuecomment-1725513619
